# Selecting part of a string for calculations (python)

Tags: python

I'm working on a for-fun-project that I will be doing some calculations with and I need some help.

one module from my program:

```
def ARK(rawArk):
    refArk = rawArk/200
    arkTrit = refArk*300
    arkMeg = refArk*333
    arkZyd = refArk*166
    print "Totals from your Arkonor:"
    print "Tritanium=", arkTrit
    print "Megacyte=", arkMeg
    print "Zydrine=", arkZyd
    return arkTrit, arkMeg, arkZyd
```

Right now it is just doing simple division and multiplication. What I want to do is be able to do this with remainders.

So if 'refArk = rawArk/200' gives a total of 16.3, I want to be able to separate the 16.0 and the 0.3 and use them as separate variables for separate calculations.

So far:

```
def ARK(rawArk):
    refArk = float(rawArk/200)
    arkTrit = refArk*300
    arkMeg = refArk*333
    arkZyd = refArk*166
    print "Totals from your Arkonor:"
    print "Tritanium=", arkTrit
    print "Megacyte=", arkMeg
    print "Zydrine=", arkZyd
    strval = str(refArk)
    head,tail = strval.split(".")
    whole = float(head)
    frac = float("."+tail)
    print whole
    print frac
    return arkTrit, arkMeg, arkZyd

def main():
    rawArk=input("How much Arkonor?")
    ARK(rawArk)
    return

main()
```

USING '450' as my input value

returns

```
How much Arkonor?450
Totals from your Arkonor:
Tritanium= 600.0
Megacyte= 666.0
Zydrine= 332.0
2.0
0.0
```

The 2.0 is right but the 0.0 should be 0.25

Removing the float() from the 'rawArk/200' spits out an error:

```
How much Arkonor?450
Totals from your Arkonor:
Tritanium= 600
Megacyte= 666
Zydrine= 332

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\eve stuff\Calculator\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\eve stuff\Calculator\test.py", line 20, in main
    ARK(rawArk)
  File "E:\eve stuff\Calculator\test.py", line 11, in ARK
    head,tail = strval.split(".")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerically

```
val1 = 22.0
val2 = 7.0
whole,frac = divmod(val1,val2)
frac = frac/val1
```

Kind of a hack but with strings

```
val = 22.0/7.0
strval = str(val)
head,tail = strval.split(".")
whole = float(head)
frac = float("."+tail)
```

either way

```
>>> frac
0.14285714286000001
>>> whole
3.0
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Always fast on the replies!!

Comment: No need to cast to a `tuple` in your hacky solution (Python will unpack a list just as easily as a tuple).

Comment: @PaulSeeb -- In fact (I just tested it) `a,b = 'ab'` even works.  Nifty.  (I wonder if I'll ever use that...)

Answer (score 1):

May be first use round function then use split

```
refArk = refArk.split(".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
intpart=int(variable)
decimalpart=variable-intpart
```

I would **guess** this to be more efficient than casting to a string and then splitting.

Answer (score 0):

The following session at the IDLE should show how to solve your problem.

```
>>> lis=str(refArk).split('.')
>>> lis[-1]='.'+lis[-1]
>>> map(float,lis)
[16.0, 0.3]
```